# Want to know the location of a script containing a variable value on opencart

Tags: php, variables, content-management-system, opencart, opencart2.x

I am new to php and opencart. I am building a opencart template in which I need to know the used variables location. for example, `$header` used in `catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\home.tpl`. But I dont know where this variable value is located. I want to know the value and location and change the value. I tide to find the variable in sublime text. I imported the full opencart project on sublime text and searched for `$header`. It only show me the scripts which are using this variable not its value. What can I do to get the location?

I also want to know if there is any documentation for changing opencart internal function, variable, scripts and where they are located.

I am using opencart 2.3.0.2 with wamp server(x64) 3.0.4 in windows 10(x64).

Comment: This will give you a overall idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the template (`.tpl`) file's respective Controller file and look for an entry in the `$data` that matches the name of the variable you're exploring.

So in your case the Controller file will be located at `catalog/controller/common/home.php`. In this Controller file look for where an element of the `$data` array is assigned to, `$data['header'] = ...`, it will be located near the bottom of the `index()` function.

In OpenCart the `$data` array inside Controller files is the means of data transfer between Controller's and Template files. So like stated before the `$data['header']` element in the Controller file is the `$header` variable in the Template file.